# how to find a person given more details on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-search

They screwed it up again. In Facebook search how do you get the option to enter more details when trying to search for someone or something? For example you want to find "Jane" who lives in "New York" etc. It used to be if you start typing the name and then click on people it gave more options but it doesn't anymore.

Comment: You can simply write all details in search bar like 'Jane who lives in New York' or 'Jane who lives in New York and studying in some_college_name' this is not the right way but you will get more appropriate result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be based on your search history and which experiment group you are in.

For example for me, based on whether I enter

- People named "Jane" who live in New York, New York
- People named "Jane" who live in New York

Will determine if I get the proper search subsection

[image: Graph Search]

You can always go directly by using the following

https://www.facebook.com/search/str/Jane/users-named/108424279189115/residents/present/intersect

This breaks up as *People named "Jane"* `str/Jane/users-named/` and *who live in New York, New York* `/108424279189115/residents/present/` with the `intersect` to get the intersection of the two sets.

'People named "Jane" who live in New York, New York'

You can also use https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests

which has these filters on the right side to choose from

[image: Filter Search]

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter the name of the person you want to search for and click the magnifying glass. Don't hit enter
2. On the left side, click on "People"

Above the search-bar, you should be able to specify your search by adding filters now.

Comment: that's how it used to work but doesn't anymore

Comment: @Suuldat : Can you please add a screenshot because I didn't see any filter option these days.